# Programmatically Click HTML button using java

Tags: java, html, button

I have one html file, and I want to make program to click that button every I run the program. I used HTMLUnit but still has an error.

```
public class checkBox {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        check();
    }

  public static void check() {
    WebClient wclient = new WebClient();    

    try(final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {

          final HtmlPage Page = wclient.getPage("file://E:\\Please.html");
          final HtmlForm Form = Page.getForms().get(1);
          final HtmlButton submit = Form.getButtonByName("submit");
          final HtmlPage nextPage = submit.click();  
          System.out.println(nextPage);
        } catch(FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    wclient.close();
  }
}
```

This is the button that I want to click.

```
input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"
```

The result shows an error

```
?? 24, 2015 10:40:10 ?? com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
??: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
?? 24, 2015 10:40:12 ?? com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
??: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
?? 24, 2015 10:40:16 ?? com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
??: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
?? 24, 2015 10:40:16 ?? com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
??: runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://www.wipo.int/romarin//shared/scripts/jquery-1.7.js] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
?? 24, 2015 10:40:16 ?? com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument getElementById
??: getElementById(script1443062416699) did a getElementByName for Internet Explorer
```

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages in comments since they lose their formatting making them unreadable. Instead, post any new code or error messages to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32752246/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before your *wclient* declaration, it will hide the unnecessary HtmlUnit logs:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```